# How to debug what is stopping ping to respond on our server?

Tags: networking, iptables, ping

We used to have a sysadmin person months ago who had disabled ping response on one of our servers. But now we want to re-enable ping response.

I tried to check if the ping was disabled from config. These values are set to 0.

```
root@dumpty:/mnt/NAS# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts
0
root@dumpty:/mnt/NAS# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all 
0
```

And here is the `sysctl.conf`:

```
root@dumpty:/mnt/NAS# cat /etc/sysctl.conf | grep icmp
#net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1
#net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 0
```

The ping is still not working. I know that the server is able to recieve ping because I can see the requests in the `tcpdump` but I don't see the outgoing responses, examples:

tcpdump capture for ping:

```
root@dumpty:/mnt/NAS# tcpdump -nni eth0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
18:39:45.260686 IP 103.227.98.242 > SEVERIP: ICMP echo request, id 4799, seq 1, length 64
18:39:46.259975 IP 103.227.98.242 > SEVERIP: ICMP echo request, id 4799, seq 2, length 64
18:39:47.260289 IP 103.227.98.242 > SEVERIP: ICMP echo request, id 4799, seq 3, length 64
18:39:48.259971 IP 103.227.98.242 > SEVERIP: ICMP echo request, id 4799, seq 4, length 64
18:39:49.261652 IP 103.227.98.242 > SEVERIP: ICMP echo request, id 4799, seq 5, length 64
18:39:50.261956 IP 103.227.98.242 > SEVERIP: ICMP echo request, id 4799, seq 6, length 64
18:39:51.260058 IP 103.227.98.242 > SEVERIP: ICMP echo request, id 4799, seq 7, length 64
18:39:52.260309 IP 103.227.98.242 > SEVERIP: ICMP echo request, id 4799, seq 8, length 64
^C
8 packets captured
13 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

I may be wrong but this is the command I found on web that's supposed to capture incoming packets:

```
root@dumpty:/mnt/NAS# tcpdump -nni eth0 -e icmp[icmptype] == 8
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
18:40:48.260108 00:10:db:ff:10:01 > bc:30:5b:da:51:a6, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 103.227.98.242 > SEVERIP: ICMP echo request, id 4799, seq 64, length 64
18:40:49.260064 00:10:db:ff:10:01 > bc:30:5b:da:51:a6, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 103.227.98.242 > SEVERIP: ICMP echo request, id 4799, seq 65, length 64
18:40:50.260119 00:10:db:ff:10:01 > bc:30:5b:da:51:a6, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 103.227.98.242 > SEVERIP: ICMP echo request, id 4799, seq 66, length 64
18:40:51.260092 00:10:db:ff:10:01 > bc:30:5b:da:51:a6, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 103.227.98.242 > SEVERIP: ICMP echo request, id 4799, seq 67, length 64
18:40:52.260285 00:10:db:ff:10:01 > bc:30:5b:da:51:a6, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 103.227.98.242 > SEVERIP: ICMP echo request, id 4799, seq 68, length 64
18:40:53.260465 00:10:db:ff:10:01 > bc:30:5b:da:51:a6, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 103.227.98.242 > SEVERIP: ICMP echo request, id 4799, seq 69, length 64
18:40:54.262405 00:10:db:ff:10:01 > bc:30:5b:da:51:a6, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 103.227.98.242 > SEVERIP: ICMP echo request, id 4799, seq 70, length 64
^C
7 packets captured
7 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

and this is outgoing

```
root@dumpty:/mnt/NAS# tcpdump -nni eth0 -e icmp[icmptype] == 0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

I don't see any outgoing packets, I also checked iptables for any rules blocking icmp

```
root@dumpty:/mnt/NAS# sudo iptables -L INPUT | grep reject
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9200 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:httpflags: FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN #conn src/32 > 15 reject-with tcp-reset
root@dumpty:/mnt/NAS# sudo iptables -L INPUT | grep icmp
REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:9200 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
root@dumpty:/mnt/NAS# sudo iptables -L INPUT | grep drop
root@dumpty:/mnt/NAS#
```

We have a reject on port 9200 but I think it shouldn't be blocking all ports? What else can stop our pings from responding? Did I miss any other config?

I tried my best to debug, any help is much appreciated.

Note: I edited the output of my console and replaced our sever IP with `SEVERIP`

EDIT:

Adding iptables OUTPUT chain

```
root@dumpty:/mnt/NAS# sudo iptables -L OUTPUT
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

EDIT2:

```
root@dumpty:/mnt/NAS# iptables -t nat -vnL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
root@dumpty:/mnt/NAS# iptables -t raw -vnL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
root@dumpty:/mnt/NAS# iptables -t mangle -vnL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Could you also include the iptables rules, if any, for the OUTPUT chain?

Comment: @RalphRönnquist added iptables OUTPUT

Comment: Does ping work if your turn off `iptables`?

Comment: Silly question, but making sure: "dumpty" indeed has an interface for SERVERIP? Check `ifconfig`. Other than that, you should check the "raw", "mangle" and "nat" tables, like `iptables -t nat -vnL`. (Probably all empty)

Comment: "dumpty also needs a return route for targeting 103.227.98.242 ... check `route -n`

Comment: @RalphRönnquist not sure what any of these mean but updated the description. Also yes dumpty does have interfaces, it can communicates with other servers over different protocols if that's what you mean. thanks for the help.

Comment: Are there any other hardware or software firewalls between source and destination?

Comment: With multiple interfaces you should run `tcpdump -ni xxx icmp` on all of them, and see which one, if any, shows a ping response. If it's the wrong interface you'll need to rework the routes. Maybe even set it up with multiple default routes aiming to ensure the response goes via the interface the request came in on. If there's no ping response, it's perhaps a kernel problem.

Comment: @Dan there are no hardware firewalls and no software firewalls to my knowledge but how do I check if there are any other software firewalls installed?

Comment: @pahnin You can try `service --status-all` or the equivalent command for your flavor, and check for `ipfw`, `iptables`, `ufw`, or other firewall services. As for hardware firewalls, make sure you are pinging the host from a machine on the same VLAN / subnet. If you can insert a switch in the network immediately behind the host without disrupting anything, you can plug in a laptop and ping from there to rule out other network devices.